# How to use Vue2 plugins on Vue3 Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am migrating my Vue2 App to use `@vue/composition-api` (Vue version still 2 not 3).

In Vue2 I use my plugins like `this.$session` however `this` won't work on Vue3. The solution I found was to use like this:

```
setup (props, context) {
  context.root.$session // works fine
  context.root.$anotherPlugin 
}
```

However in Vue3 `context.root` is `@deprecated` so when I migrate to Vue3 it will not work anymore.

Is there any other way to access Vue instance inside `setup()`? I think if I could access it I can use those plugins normally on Vue3.

Comment: One way to do it is to import Vue from "vue" and just use Vue.session (without the dollar sign).

Comment: hi, im having same situation. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

#### Use `provide` & `inject`

**Provide**

```js
const app = createApp(App);
app.provide('someVarName', someVar);  // Providing to all components here
```

**Inject**:

```
const { inject } = Vue;
...
setup() {
  const someVar = inject('someVarName');   // injecting in a component that wants it
}
```